How can i use "--chucnk-size when importing an Azure db?
I am trying to import a azure db backup .I want to use the chunk-size parameter. I am using
  az sql db import --resource-group <resource_group_name> --server <server_name> --name <database_name> --storage-key <storage_account_key> --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri <storage_account_uri> --administrator-login <admin_username> --administrator-login-password <admin_password> --authentication-type SQL --chunk-size-mb 100

But it says "z : ERROR: unrecognized arguments: --chunk-size-mb 100".
How can i import in small amounts to combat memry issues ?
Or do i use SQLPackage to do this ?


ERROR: unrecognized arguments: --chunk-size-mb 100

As the above error states --chunk-size-mb is unrecognized argument meant that Azure CLI doesn't support that argument to combat the memory. Below is another method which uses SHRINKDATABASE to combat the database memory. It can be used after importing the bacpac into the Azure SQL DB. Follow the below steps to combat the memory of the database:
Below code is used to import a .bacpac file into the Azure SQL database:
$ az sql db import \
--admin-password Balaji@53 \
--admin-user admin02 \
--storage-key <storage_key> \
--storage-key-type StorageAccessKey \
--storage-uri https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net/cont1/db1.bacpac \
--name db1 \
--resource-group <rg_name> \
--server server6391

The database is successfully imported into the Azure SQL DB as shown in the below output.
{
  "blobUri": "https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net/cont1/db1.bacpac",
  "databaseName": "db1",
  "errorMessage": null,
  "id": "4bfa83bc-f009-4a24-83d1-145935dfa64c",
  "lastModifiedTime": "5/15/2024 9:02:04 AM",
  "name": "4bfa83bc-f009-4a24-83d1-145935dfa64c",
  "privateEndpointConnections": [],
  "queuedTime": "5/15/2024 9:00:21 AM",
  "requestId": "4bfa83bc-f009-4a24-83d1-145935dfa64c",
  "requestType": "ImportToExistingDatabase",
  "serverName": "server6391",
  "status": "Completed",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/importExportOperationResults"
}

Use the below query to shrink the database.
DBCC SHRINKFILE(db_name, target_percent);

Output:


Refer this document for more information on SHRINK.


the database is a live database , DO I RUN THE SHRINKFILE on the database before i do a backup ? Will this impact performance or cause any errors ? Because the import cmd you use is exactly what i use.

As you want to combat memory, you can shrink after importing bacpac into the db. Make sure to perform a full database backup before shrinking it may useful if there are any issues raised.

do you mean shrink the bacpac file ? if so how do i do that ?

Refer this document on how to shrink a file.

I first export which gives a bacpac file of about 20Gig. Then do i shrink that ?

You can shrink a database after importing the bacpac into the Azure SQL DB as shown in the above answer.
